# I need to batch move files from one location to another, and put them in pre-existing folders with the same first 7 characters

Tags: macos, applescript, file-transfer, automation, javascript

I am looking to automate moving large amounts of files.
Basically I have one location on our network full of .zip files.
They are all named like "12-3456.zip" etc.
I need to move each of these .zip file to a different location on our network which contains pre existing folders already named. Need to move the .zip file to the folder with the same name.
I found something similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397954/applescript-move-files-to-folder-which-name-begins-with-first-7-characters-of) but is seems to choke on large amounts of files.

Any help/advice/experience with similar problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Why thawed applescript and javascript?

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to move from one directory the .zip files into a different directory in which the subdirectories with the same name as the .zip?

Comment: how many files are we talking about?